# Deciding Theme and Colour Scheme For Trivia-Based Game

Tags: games

I started work on an Android-based trivia-like game. You basically pick a topic (eg. volcanoes) and get a random set of 10 questions out of a bigger pool.

I'm really struggling to pick a colour scheme, and also, to pick a style or theme to use -- every choice seems arbitrary at this point. I do have a "company" site and colour scheme, but I doubt if that would be the right choice here.

How do I decide which theme/style/colour-scheme to use?

Comment: This should probably be asked on Graphic Design, though it's somewhat of an unanswerable question short of 'do lots of research and browsing and sketching'

Comment: @DA01 that sucks. It was bounced from GameDev to UX and now to graphic design? Sigh. I'll just apply myself and stop asking these types of questions.

Comment: Yea, the visual design end of StackExchange has been fragmented quite a bit. It is confusing at times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate on the design:

Use a color scheme generator like [Kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com/) to select a set of colors that looks decent. Put the colors in your code as constants so it's easy to change them.

Mock up the design. Look at it and see if it's pleasing.

If you like it, show it to some friends. Do they like it? Do they even notice? Is anything confusing?

Incorporate that feedback and continue refining.

Answer (score 2):

Every trivia game that I've ever seen has followed the conventions from the board game *Trivia*.  To some extent, I think that people have come to expect this, but it also gives some visual information.

If I see a **light blue** background or border I expect it is to do with **geography**. If it's **yellow**, I expect it is a **history** question.

While this isn't your overall colour scheme it could be useful to use for the questions.

Other than that, when choosing a colour scheme, try and choose one that visually impaired and colour blind people can also differentiate.  There are some great tools to help with this, such as **[Chrome Daltonize!](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/efeladnkafmoofnbagdbfaieabmejfcf)**.

The overall decision is up to you.  **You have to decide what you think will be best**.